# Nginx + Unicorn subdomain virtual hosting failure (timeouts)

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, reverse-proxy, unicorn

I have a server set on a VPS serving up a production Rails app via Nginx + Unicorn.  Presently this works fine with the following conf files:

- [nginx.conf](https://gist.github.com/62a23445e1eb644df1db#file_nginx.conf)
- [unicorn.conf](https://gist.github.com/62a23445e1eb644df1db#file_unicorn.conf)

However the added subdomain of `staging.appname.tld` ends up yielding the following error in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

```
2012/08/20 16:57:39 [error] 24673#0: *174 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: staging.appname.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.appname_staging.sock:/", host: "staging.appname.com"
2012/08/20 16:58:17 [error] 24673#0: *178 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: staging.appname.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.appname_staging.sock:/", host: "staging.appname.com"
2012/08/20 16:59:29 [error] 24673#0: *182 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: staging.appname.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.appname_staging.sock:/", host: "staging.appname.com"
```

The configurations proffering this error are:

- [nginx_staging.conf](https://gist.github.com/62a23445e1eb644df1db#file_nginx_staging.conf)
- [unicorn_staging.conf](https://gist.github.com/62a23445e1eb644df1db#file_unicorn_staging.conf)

Additionally, the socks do exist!  If we look in /tmp/ we see: `unicorn.appname.sock` and `unicorn.appname_staging.sock`

And [here](http://j.mp/NCFbDj) is the `nginx -V` output.

It would seem as though something is off in the config, however I'm just not seeing it.  Could someone please advise as to where this error is coming from and how to properly set up subdomains such as a staging environment in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything that's wrong in your config, although some minor stuff to improve but nothing that should break it. Could you please activate debug logging and post the log here.

And please have a look at the following revised configuration (with activated debug logging).

```
upstream unicorn_appname_staging {
  server unix:/tmp/unicron.appname_staging.sock max_fails=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  index index.html;
  root /home/deployer/apps/appname/staging/current/public;
  server_name staging.appname.com;

  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/staging.appname.com.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/staging.appname.com.error.log debug;
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;

  location / {
    location ^~ /assets/ {
      gzip_static on;
      expires max;
      add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    try_files $uri @unicorn_appname_staging;
  }

  location @unicorn_appname_staging {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn_appname_staging;
  }
}
```

Comment: When adding `debug` to the end of `root /home/deployer/apps/appname/staging/current/public;` nginx replied with the following error on restart: Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "root" directive in ...  Running version `1.2.2-0ubuntu0ppa2~precise`.

Comment: SORRY! Fully my mistake, I put it on the wrong spot. I corrected it, now it's correct. Again SORRY!

Comment: additionally there are no additional results when I append `debug` to the error_log line.

Comment: Okay, so yes, I already had tried that addition earlier and then again here, but there is no additional output in the error log. It makes me think that there must be some going wrong with unicorn, however it works fine in production and the sock is present...

Comment: What kind of nginx package have you installed? Can you add the output of `nginx -V` to your question.

Comment: `nginx -V` yields: http://j.mp/NCFbDj

Comment: So it actually was compiled with the `--with-debug` flag. Maybe it's best if you activate debug on global basis - in your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file (search for the error_log directive there, if it doesn't exist create it).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4573/discussion-between-ylluminate-and-fleshgrinder)

Comment: Having appended this to both the main conf and the staging app conf, I still get no additional log output when this error occurs.

Comment: It turns out that it was indeed a unicorn issue that was very well hidden.  It is a real shame that there is not a better connection between logging facilities of these two servers.

Comment: Okay, great that you were able to pin it down. :)

Comment: @ylluminate would you update the question to reflect the problem that you fixed?  I cannot infer it from your comment history - [and others would like to know](http://www.xkcd.com/979/)